# How to change report.html in Robot Framework?

Tags: robotframework

I want change a FAIL case to PASS in my report.html, but I don't know how to achieve it, could anyone know how to change or re-generate a report.html?

Comment: you can generate report and log using **rebot output.xml**, however i dont think you can change fail to pass

Comment: You can use a prerebotmodifier to change the verdicts. Read the user guide, it has examples.